# I have a problem BNB smart chain close my contract

Tags: blockchain

Sir my amount was automatically transfer to another account and my money was show in hashrate what can I do to return my money
0x6c7dd643c0aD2cd87dC51a42B4c3475E6Ae3833a

Answer (score 0):

https://bscscan.com/tx/0x86ba6bccdfb2cb946fc6edce07c7a49d365d8fc90726af7b5816f92544c13607 There. You signed a transaction that literally means "i'm allowing address 0x19981855608d7b8be7875ea313b2b2d7b8a9eecc to take all my USDT and  use it as they want". You might want to warn tether so they can freeze this address and all addresses associated to it, but your funds are unfortunately lost.

Comment: And also of course, never use this address again